# How to set doctype in CQ5.6?

Tags: html, aem, doctype

I've been working with **CQ5.6** for about a month now and our test site is almost done in terms of components.

However when we try to validate the pages we run into problems because AEM puts `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` above all our pages.

Now, I can't find any place where the Doctype is explicitly declared in our code. Nor is the HTML tag in our code, so i presume AEM wraps these around everything.

First I tried deleting the import of the doctype in our page component and replacing it with `<!DOCTYPE html>` but then we ended up with 2 doctype declarations. First the XHTML one, then a wrapped `<html>` tag and then my HTML5 one.

I've read in the docs that you can set the doctype using the cq:doctype property, but no clue where I should add that property to.

I also tried putting this above the head tags in our page components, but to no avail:

```
<% Doctype doc= Doctype.valueOf("HTML_5");
   doc.toRequest(request);
%> 
<%= Doctype.fromRequest(request).getDeclaration() %>
```

Could anyone explain to me how or where I could **set the doctype** to HTML5 for our project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CQ doesn't wrap the page with Doctype by default. It might have been the case where your page component would have had `foundation/components/page` as its parent (`sling:resourceSuperType` property).

Due to the [component hierarchy and inheritance](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#Component%20Hierarchy%20and%20Inheritance), the Doctype included in the foundation page.jsp is getting included for your page, and hence it appears as if it is wrapping up your HTML.

The page.jsp includes doctype as shown below

```
<%= Doctype.fromRequest(request).getDeclaration() %>
```

You can avoid this by overriding the content of foundation page.jsp within your page component itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Guess I'm still very much a rookie at CQ5 / AEM.

I've also discovered that you can set the doctype to html5 for all your pages in a project by adding a `cq:doctype` property with value `HTML_5` to the `jcr:content` node of `etc/designs/<projectname>`

Answer (score 0):

In this path `foundation/components/page/_NAME_` you are able to override your  `head.jsp` file which contains the `DOCTYPE` definition and the HEAD statements as well.

Next you can see an example of the original one: 
[head.jsp example](http://dev.cqblueprints.com/svn/bootstrap/tags/1.0.0/cqblueprints-bootstrap-view/src/main/content54/jcr_root/apps/bootstrap/components/bootstrapPage/head.jsp)

If you didn't define your own custom template, that's the reason. You may need to create a folder (`/foundation/components/page/_NAME_/`) with the next structure:

```
head.jsp
body.jsp
dialog.xml
```